# How to print from Canon PIXMA G2070 from Raspberry 4 OS?

Tags: printing

My printer is **Canon Pixma 2070** (CANON PIXMA 2000 series).
I don't know how to print from my Raspberry Pi 4.
Please give a solution to print in USB (orelse wireless method by Wi=fi as my Pi supports it).
Also how to use the economy mode for printing ?

Comment: what have you tried? ... how did your attempt fail? ... this is really a Linux question, not a Raspberry Pi question

Comment: Welcome. I realize the duplicate is not exactly the same, but it ends with the issue that Canon do not provide drivers for ARM devices (this includes all Raspberry Pi models), which complicates things and might mean you are out of luck.  More hopefully, see: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=329460  General CUPS documentation is here: https://www.cups.org/documentation.html